# Keep most HTML after link clicked

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Hi i want to make an effect similar to what this site does http://www.hffm.co.uk/

When you change the page the url up top changes but the content in the sidebar and header stays the same. - i am also curious if this affects SEO.

They stay the same - and do not reload with the page - i figure it has to be some ajax thing? Curious what a system like this is called.

The point is in their case they dont want to interrupt the radio on a link change.

Answer (score 0):

To update the specific part of the page it can be achieved through Ajax and JQuery. Basically both of the those works on the client side which means that website doesn't refresh. You can always make a Ajax request to the server which can return the content in a Json format and that content can be reflected on the page using Jquery.

This is only just a overview of how ajax/Jquery works. But you need to be more specific in what you are trying to achieve and what you have done so far.

Comment: Exactly the same as that link I use javascript find jquery is for lazy people . I'm using WordPress